# How to delete the scrollbar in my pages?

Tags: pages

Heyho!

On my website, but only in Opera, I see a scrollbar on every page. It looks aweful and the scrollbar is not even necessary, because it only wants to scroll a tiny bit.

What did I do wrong and how could I keep the browser from creating scrollbars there?

The page is [www.coldsilence.de](http://www.coldsilence.de). Thanks!

Comment: It's probably because the browser thinks you have some content that's too large for the screen or too large for the containing element. You'll probably have to inspect the site in Opera's developer tools to work out what exactly.

Comment: Or as a CSS change "overflow: auto" or "overflow: hidden" might work too ([StackOverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436778/243245)). I don't know if you can easily make that conditional on Opera though.

Comment: Thanks, the Overflow:Hidden did the job! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Rup post answers as answers not comments